# ESP8266-01: How to work with USB to ESP8266

Tags: esp8266

I want to flash micropython on an ESP8266-01, using [this wifi adaptor](https://www.ebay.com/itm/RCmall-USB-to-ESP8266-ESP-01-Wireless-Wifi-Adapter-Module-CH340G-Driver-IC/112469773389?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649).

Since I don't succeed in doing so (fail using esptool as I do with other ESP8266/ ESP32 I use), I'm asking for your assistance in this procedure, mainly what is the functionality of switch on module.

Installation. Tried to install using [installation guide](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/esp8266/esp8266/tutorial/intro.html),—didn't pass to level 1.5.

Tries descripbtion:

1) install [drivers](https://github.com/MPParsley/ch340g-ch34g-ch34x-mac-os-x-driver)

2) driver detected on OS:

`MacBook-Pro:~ guy$ ls /dev/tty.*
/dev/tty.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port    /dev/tty.wchusbserial1430`

3)switch toggle on USB adapter to `prog`.

4) connect to mac ( using usb C adaptor ).

5)1st try, **react OK**:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ guy$ esptool.py --port /dev/tty.wchusbserial1430  flash_id
esptool.py v2.5.0
Serial port /dev/tty.wchusbserial1430
Connecting....
Detecting chip type... ESP8266
Chip is ESP8266EX
Features: WiFi
MAC: 68:c6:3a:d7:0d:be
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Manufacturer: 85
Device: 6014
Detected flash size: 1MB
Hard resetting via RTS pin...
```

6) **ANY** additional command needs plugging adaptor out, and back in ( empirical - don't know why ),

7) erasing ( took 0.0 s ?? ):

```
MacBook-Pro:~ guy$ esptool.py --port /dev/tty.wchusbserial1430  --chip esp8266 erase_flash
esptool.py v2.5.0
Serial port /dev/tty.wchusbserial1430
Connecting....
Chip is ESP8266EX
Features: WiFi
MAC: 68:c6:3a:d7:0d:be
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Erasing flash (this may take a while)...
Chip erase completed successfully in 0.0s
Hard resetting via RTS pin...
```

8) writing flash ( tried also with auto detect size ):

```
MacBook-Pro:~ guy$ esptool.py --port /dev/tty.wchusbserial1430  --baud 460800 write_flash  0 ~/Downloads/esp8266-20180511-v1.9.4.bin 
esptool.py v2.5.0
Serial port /dev/tty.wchusbserial1430
Connecting....
Detecting chip type... ESP8266
Chip is ESP8266EX
Features: WiFi
MAC: 68:c6:3a:d7:0d:be
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Changing baud rate to 460800
Changed.
Configuring flash size...

A fatal error occurred: Timed out waiting for packet header
```